# How to model Linear Regression with unequal variance in only one direction?

Tags: regression, model, heteroscedasticity

Say you have data that looks like the left plot, where $Y$ is the response and $X$ is the covariate. The right plot is after $log_2$ transformation of $X$ and $Y$, which seems to look better, so let's model the right plot instead.

[image: Data Plots]

It looks almost like you could use simple linear regression, perhaps on the minimum of $Y$ or $log_2(Y)$. Or maybe linear regression with unequal variance, like weighted least squares. But the variation only goes above that minimum of $Y$ or $log_2(Y)$ line. Is there any regression model that captures this?

Comment: Are the Y counts?

Comment: @mdewey No, Y > 0 and is continuous. Y is the time in seconds.

Comment: Is there a scientific hypothesis to explain the fact that the minimum appears to increase with x? I do not think I have ever seen a plot quite like it.